# Counting the number of times a group in a pandas groupby object has a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
   hostname    level
0  host1         1
1  host2         2
2  host3         3
3  host1         3
4  host1         4
5  host2         2
...
```

When I group this dataframe by hostname and get the value counts of the severity column using

```
>>>frame.groupby("hostname").level.value_counts()
```

I get

```
hostname  level
host1       1      1
            3      1
            4      1
host2       2      2
host3       3      1
...
```

where the third column is the number of occurrences of that level for that particular hostname. I want to create from this data a dataframe that looks like this

```
  hostname    level1_occur    level2_occur    level3_occur    level4_occur
0  host1           1               0              1              1
1  host2           0               2              0              0
2  host3           0               0              0              1
```

where I have individual columns for the number of occurrences of a level for each hostname, but I am having trouble finding anything that will do this. Is there an efficient way of doing this ala. not looping through the entire dataframe over and over again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.crosstab(df.hostname,df.level)
Out[360]: 
level     1  2  3  4
hostname            
host1     1  0  1  1
host2     0  2  0  0
host3     0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unstack`:

```
dft = frame.groupby("hostname").level.value_counts()
dft.unstack(fill_value=0)\
   .add_prefix('level')\
   .add_suffix('_occur')\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
level hostname  level1_occur  level2_occur  level3_occur  level4_occur
0        host1             1             0             1             1
1        host2             0             2             0             0
2        host3             0             0             1             0
```